Ontological equivalence in Hinduism?
So different interpretations of quantum mechanics lead to the same equations and consensus of quantum mechanics (like many worlds interpretation and Copenhagen). I dub this as ontologically equivalent.
Interestingly, there is another ontologically equivalent phenomena I am aware of in religion. I have a musing that ontological equivalence was discovered early on in eastern traditions?
While I can't provide direct quotes from the Vedas, I can offer you some concepts and principles that highlight the Vedic perspective on the diversity of beliefs and the goal of realizing the oneness of all existence and the divine nature of the self for example:
In Hinduism God is manifest in many forms and even atheism is considered a valid path or "no form".
Ekam Sat Vipraha Bahudha Vadanti: This Vedic phrase translates to "Truth is one, but the wise express it in various ways." It acknowledges the existence of different paths and perspectives while recognizing the underlying unity of truth.
Did the eastern traditions have the idea of ontological equivalence but articulated differently?

Assuming they lead to same equations and consensus, then why you specifically need to mention to dub since without dubbing they still lead to same result, head upon head?...

@DoubleKnot I have included some references hopefully it's better? And yes they lead to the same result ..

Copenhagen, many-worlds, pilot-wave, these do differ primarily at an ontological level: and that they end up coinciding at a more operational and mundane one is not even totally precise, it is only strictly true in the usual and for now testable "regimes".  OTOH, eastern traditions are only improperly concerned with ontological issues, the "unity of truth" exists beyond a mundane notion of "truth".  TL;DR I think you are misusing "ontology".

@DoubleKnot Yeah I too felt similarly: It's not that interpretations of QM lead to equations but rather equations lead to interpretations. At least chronologically/historically. I.e. QM arose from physicists having the courage to say: Lets put aside ontic/epistemic presumptions and impartially allow where the observations lead..


QM theories have completely different ontologies; that's in fact their main difference, as the results are the same.

A basic underlying concept of Hinduism and Eastern (religions) in general, is that the "true" essence of things is unconceivable and indescribable by human beings, so a personal-expreriencial approach is all that is left to attain higher knowledge. Because of this, there is in fact no specific ontological representation of things; you could say that these religions have no ontologies; the definition and essence of being(s) is a personal one (subjective) and cannot be expressed inside a specific framework of thinking.

What you may mean, is that as QM opened the way to a non-mechanistic interpretation of reality, this seems to have a correlation to an Eastern way of thinking about reality; but that's another question...



Could you please elaborate a bit on what you consider the different ontologies of QM-theories? What are the entities and relations characterizing the different ontologies?

@Jo Wehler, Huge topic ... for ex. the probabilistic represenration of the "state" in the Copenhagen interpretation is considered an intrinsic property of reality, in such a way that the atoms are seen not as real things but as potentialities. [PHYSICS AND PHILOSOPHY, Heisenberg]

@Jo Wehler, on the other hand, other interpretations, try to preserve the materialistic ontology, by considering the "state" as the probability of the positioning.

Does the Copenhagen interpretation really consider physical systems like atoms to be not real things but potentialities? Isn't the state of an elementary particle between two observations considered a set of potentialities? - Can you give a reference because you point to Heisenberg's book? Thanks.

@Jo Wehler, p 184-186, but as we have already talked about, you should read the whole book. https://archive.org/details/physics-and-philosophy-the-revolution-in-modern-scirnce-werner-heisenberg-f.-s.-c.-northrop

By taking into account @More Anonymous's comment regarding my interpretation (see my other answer -3) of his question, I will post my thoughts regarding the proposed equivalence of concepts between QM and Hinduism.
I believe that reality - in its essence - is objective and concrete, what's subjective is its expression in the physical world (manifestation), since the interpretation of the manifestation (itself, not the way it became of) is based on personal perspective.
Hinduism, by acknowledging this, tries to remove the personal perspective (subjectivity) from the equation, by removing the thoughts from the self and leaving space for the all, i.e. the objective to give the meaning.
On the other hand, in QM we have come to realise this fact - that the manifestation cannot be objectified; it is only possible to assign probabilities to it - the hard way. And I say the hard way, because what was initially thought of as inability to predict, became an intrinstic property of reality.
So, we are coming close, and perhaps soon we will all agree: it's the whole that gives meaning to its parts and not the other way.

I understand that this view can be considered heretic from a western point of view, even in a philosophical context, but I believe that it is fruitful to correlate with concepts in other cultural contexts, even in a poetic form.


Quantum theory (QM): Already in the early days of QM it was
recognized that the two formulation of  “Heisenberg” picture and the
“Schroedinger” picture are mathematically equivalent. To call them
ontologically equivalent presupposes that you first clarify the
ontologies you mean. Unfortunately your post does not tell any details
about the ontologies in question.
The mathematical formulation of QM is not the biggest problem. A
century problem in physics are the different interpretations of the
theory. Do you mean that these interpretations are based on different
ontologies? If yes, it would be helpful to hear about the candidate
ontologies.

The Vedas: The Rgveda is a collection of hymns and ritual texts. It
is based on the concept of  correct offering to force the gods to
fulfill the human wishes.
“Realizing the oneness of all existence
and the divine nature of the self” is a characteristic of the later
Upanishads, which circle around  the concepts of atman and brahman.
The aim is to find a correspondence between anthropology and a cosmic
principle. Again one can ask about the ontologies which underly the
speculations from the Upanishads.
The other three Vedas besides the
Rgveda seem to me liturgic textbooks for the correct ritual of
offering. I think they do not add a new aspect to your subject.

A statement like “Truth is one, but the wise express it in various
ways” is a nice aphorism. But before one has to  express explicitly
and in clear words at least two fundamental insights, and to show
their equivalence.


Your final question about a principle of “ontological equivalence” can only be discussed when the underlying ontological concepts are clarified before.

The different ontologies would be something like many worlds and Copenhagen interpretation

@MoreAnonymous What do you mean by "something like"? Which entities specify the many-worlds ontology, which the Copenhagen ontology of QM, and why are both equivalent?

Jo both of them are equivalent because if I do not ask human A and human B which interpretation of QM they are using and solely see the experiments and knowledge of QM then from a black box perspective I cannot know which interpretation/ontology they are employing

@MoreAnonymous IMO it is not meaningful to discuss questions on ontology without specifying the ontology under question by specifying at least its entities and their relations.

I'm not an expert at Hindu philosophy so I avoid overreaching. I have however, provided a link. Maybe someone well versed in Hinduism can provide some reference?

@user66697 I agree with Ioannis interpretation of my question ...
